# Creating a question/solution document from one source file

Tags: koma-script, multiple-files

I would like to create a test/exam kind of document together with a solution sheet from a single .tex file.

Both the test and the solution sheets are going to look almost identical. I've been doing something like that successfully in exam class where I'd just add `\ifprintanswers` in the document to mark the answers and change `\documentclass{exam}` to `\documentclass[answers]{exam}` when I want to compile the answer document.

How can I achieve something similar without using exam class, say in scrartcl class?

Even better would be, if I could create both documents within a single run of pdflatex and without editing anything in the textfile between runs.

Comment: Have a look at the ton of dedicated packages for this https://ctan.org/topic/exam and https://ctan.org/topic/exercise

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the commands that the `comment` package offers. Here is an example.

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{comment}
\newcommand\ExamWithoutSolution[1]{%
  \excludecomment{solution}%
  \include{#1}%
}
\newcommand\ExamWithSolution[1]{%
  \includecomment{solution}%
  \include{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\ExamWithoutSolution{myexam}
\ExamWithSolution{myexam}
\end{document}

% myexam.tex
\title{The Christmas Exam}
\author{Prof.\ John I.Q.\ Nerdelbaum Frink Jr.}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item Compute $1+1$.

\begin{solution}
 The answer is $2$.
\end{solution}

\item Compute $1-1$.

\begin{solution}
 The answer is $0$.
\end{solution}
\end{enumerate}
```

Running `pdflatex` once on `main.tex` yields a document with two pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can define a switch with `\newif`:

```
\newif\ifSolution % defines \ifSolution, \Solutiontrue, and \Solutionfalse
\Solutiontrue     % set flag "Solution" to true
\Solutionfalse    % set flag "Solution" to false
\ifSolution ... \else ... \fi % Execute code depending on flag "Solution"
```

Here is the example from my other solution, resulting in the same output:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newif\ifSolution
\newcommand\ExamWithoutSolution[1]{%
  \Solutionfalse
  \include{#1}%
}
\newcommand\ExamWithSolution[1]{%
  \Solutiontrue
  \include{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\ExamWithoutSolution{myexam}
\ExamWithSolution{myexam}
\end{document}

% myexam.tex
\title{The Christmas Exam}
\author{Prof.\ John I.Q.\ Nerdelbaum Frink Jr.}
\maketitle

\begin{enumerate}
\item Compute $1+1$.

\ifSolution
The answer is $2$.
\fi

\item Compute $1-1$.

\ifSolution
The answer is $0$.
\fi
\end{enumerate}
```